# How to convert to $('#' + $(this).val()).show() vanilla javascirpt

Tags: javascript

How to convert this code to vanilla?

```
$('#optionselector').change(function(){
    $('.option-type').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

I cannot figure out the last line:

```
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
  if (elem.addEventListener)
    elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent)
    elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
}

addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById('optionselector'), 'change', function() {
    document.querySelector('.option-type').style.display = 'none';

  });
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oldcastle/f7dop93z/7/)

Comment: `#` marks an ID selector, and `$(this).val()` is the actual ID value it should select an element by here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just:

```
document.querySelector('#' + this.value).style.display = 'block';
```

See below for live example:

```js
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
  if (elem.addEventListener)
    elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent)
    elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
}

addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById('optionselector'), 'change', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.d-none').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
    if(this.value !== "")
      document.querySelector('#' + this.value).style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="option_type" class="option-type form-control mb-4" id="optionselector">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="text_type">Text Input</option>
<option value="select_type">Select Dropdown</option>
<option value="radio_type">Radiobox</option>
</select>

<div class="d-none" id="text_type">TEXT</div>

<div class="d-none" id="select_type">SELECT</div>

<div class="d-none" id="radio_type">RADIO</div>
```

Comment: Nice, but now the 'document.querySelector('.option-type').style.display = 'none';' doesnt work.

Comment: @OldCastle one has nothing that I can see to do with the other. My suggestion is post your html and/or provide a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: I update the answer with https://jsfiddle.net/oldcastle/f7dop93z/7/

Comment: @OldCastle in your fiddle `option_type` is the select element's _name_ not its _class_ (and you're searching for `option-type` not `option_type` too!). So because an error is raised the next line never even executes. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, i'm checking that now. But on your example, the select disapares once its selected.

Comment: @OldCastle isnt that what you _wanted_ to happen? what are you trying to set to `style.display = 'none';`? what was `option-type` meant to be targetting? I assumed that was the select

Comment: ooooh... was it the other `div`s??

Comment: yeah... i want o display the other divs based on what i select.

Comment: It's working! One last thing. How can I suppress the error msg on console if I select none?

Comment: @OldCastle `if(this.value !== ""){ ... }`